# C (std=c99) pointer to structs memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, c99, local-variables

So, this is working fine... that means, no compiler errors, it seems that there is no memory leak and it is doing what I wanted it to do. That said should it be working? When I go to books_init I send a local variable to collection, doesn't it mean that when I go back to main it shouldn't be working? (or undefined behavior?). Also, in case you say that I have to malloc it, do I have to free it after? (commented on cleanup)

```
/* pseudo struct Collection{
    size_t size, capacity;
    Volume *volumes;
} */

void collection_init(Collection *col, size_t capacity){
    col->size = 0;
    col->capacity = capacity;
    col->volumes = malloc(sizeof(Volume) * capacity);
}

void collection_resize(Collection *col, size_t capacity){
    Volume *v = realloc(col->volumes, capacity * sizeof(Volume));
    if(!v) return;
    col->capacity = capacity;
    col->volumes = v;
}

void collection_add(Collection *col, Volume *volume){
    if(col->size >= col->capacity)
        collection_resize(col, col->capacity * 2);
    col->volumes[col->size++] = *volume;
}

void collection_clean(Collection *col){
    //for(vol : col->vol) free(vol);
    //should I free every element or just volumes?
    free(col->volumes);
}

void books_init(Collection *col){
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; ++i){
        Volume v = {.swag = i};
        collection_add(col, &v);
    }
}    



int main(){
    Collection col;
    collection_init(&col, 10); 
    books_init(&col);
    for(int i = 0; i < col.size; ++i){
        printf("\tVol[%d].id = %d\n", i, col.volumes[i].swag);
    }
    collection_clean(&col);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Is this a quiz? What is the first price?

Comment: when calling `realloc()`, always save the returned value in a temporary variable, then check that temporary variable to be sure it is not NULL before assigning to the target variable.   Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails (which it can do) then the original pointer to allocated memory is lost, so cannot be passed to `free()`.  This results in a memory leak.   Also if that NULL pointer is dereferenced, that is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: regarding this line: `//should I free every element or just volumes?`,  the code should pass to `free()` every pointer that contains a value gotten by malloc() or calloc() or realloc()

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, the posted code must (cleanly) compile.  the actual input that causes a problem must be included.  the actual output must be included and the expected output must be included.  The the question must contain a clear description of the problem (and preferably) some indication of what you have done to fix the problem.

Comment: @user3629249 FWIW the code already saves the return value in a temporary.

Comment: this line: `col->volumes[col->size++] = *volume;` will not work as expected.  per the posted code, `volumn` is an instance of a struct not an intrinsic C variable.  So the line should be: `memcpy( &(col->volumes[col->size++]), volume, sizeof( Volume ) );`  And to avoid certain 'side effects' I would increment the `col->size` in the next statement rather than in the statement that copies the data

Comment: Yeah, the error handling is not good (I know) but I'm already checking it, just need a simple return to not fall in that after. About the "runtime problem" the question was: There was none, and I was quite expecting it because I didn't know "col->volumes[col->size++] = *volume;" made a copy of the content. Sorry for no description of the output, my bad. But it's easy to see that the output is "Vol[0].id = 0\n\tVol[1].id = 1"... I didn't post all the code because it was more like a question and not really a "problem" since it was working and is quite a simple app.

Comment: @user3386109,  your correct, I did not say that was a problem in the posted code.     However, there is a problem with the call to `malloc()` in the *_init() function because it fails to check (!=NULL) the returned value.  This exposes the lack of success/failure status from each sub function is not passed to the caller, resulting in the caller thinking the sub function was successful.   When the sub function is not successful, undefined behaviour occurs and probably a seg fault event

Comment: given your latest comment ` it was more like a question and not really a "problem`  it is off-topic for stackoverflow.  Suggest moving it to codereview.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a review of working code.  Suggest moving to codereview.com

Comment: @user3629249 "Compiled successfully" is too low a quality standard for Code Review. The question isn't even consistent between `volume` and `volumes`.

Comment: Sorry if it was off-topic, could you just link the rule that marks it as such? And sorry for the inconsistency in that pseudo code @200_success , will edit it.

Comment: This question is actually a very good one. Most novice programmers assume that if their code **appears** to work, that it's completely correct. They don't even consider the possibility that the code may contain **undefined behavior**. PedroDavid showed a great deal of wisdom by asking this question. And he even pointed out a couple places where the code might have undefined behavior. So this was not a "How can I improve my code?" question. It was "Does my code have undefined behavior?"  Whether it's better here, or on Code Review, seems debatable, but I think it belongs here.

Comment: @200_success,  I was thinking the OP stated that the code works and they were asking a question about improvements

Comment: @user3629249 After the correction, the code would be welcome in Code Review, but the questions about how to do memory management correctly would be better asked on Stack Overflow. Pedro appears to be more interested in having a specific question answered about how the code should work than in open-ended critique, so it is more appropriate as a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in `books_init`

```
Volume v = {.swag = i};
```

creates a local variable called `v` with member `swag` initialized to `i`. The address of that variable is then passed to `collection_add`. That is allowed because `v` is still in scope.

This line in `collection_add`

```
col->volumes[col->size++] = *volume;
```

makes a **copy** of the contents of the `Volume` structure, and stores that copy in the memory that was allocated in `collection_init`.

After `collection_add` returns, the variable `v` in `books_init` goes out of scope, but that's OK because the contents of `v` were copied and saved in the memory that `col->volumes` points to.

When the program ends, `collection_clean` only needs

```
free(col->volumes);
```

to remove all of the `Volume` copies from memory.

The only flaw I see in your program occurs if `realloc` fails. In that case, you still write to the `Volume` array. This will cause a buffer overrun and memory corruption. To avoid this, the `collection_add` function should verify that the `collection_resize` function succeeded before performing the copy. For example, you could check again that `col->capacity > col->size` before doing the copy.

**TL;DR** your code is fine as long as the `realloc` always succeeds.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking that it should be that and even went and tried to check the generated assembly... "tried"... And about that "flaw" it was already in my scope, I was thinking about a return value, but your idea seems pretty nice (simple and readable without a "random value" or assigning a const/define/enum).

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help :)